# Can't access file in Alias-directory via download-script

Tags: php, xampp

i'm working on a download-script atm. The php-files are located in the xampp htdocs-directory, while the folder containing the files is located on an external HDD.

I've already set up an Alias for the external drive:

```
<Directory "h:/Filme">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory> 
Alias /filme "H:/Filme"
```

This is the download-script:

```
<?php

$download_dir = "filme/";
$files = array(
                "1" => "300.avi",
                "2" => "asdf.txt",
                "3" => "doc.pdf",
                "4" => "bild3.jpg",
              );
$file = $download_dir.$files[$_GET['id']];

header("Content-Type: x-type/subtype");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$files[$_GET['id']]);

readfile($file);
?>
```

Download is started via:

```
<a href="download.php?id=2">asdf.txt</a><BR>
```

Now, the problem is the following:
i can acces files, like for example asdf.txt, by typing *localhost/filme/asdf.txt* in my browser's address-bar.
However, the file i can download using the download-script says:

```
 <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  filesize(): stat failed for filme/asdf.txt in <b>C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\download.php</b> on line <b>26</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  readfile(filme/asdf.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\download.php</b> on line <b>32</b><br />
```

And i honestly have NO idea how to fix this O.o

TY for answers etc <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between the path structure in HTTP and in the file system. PHP knows nothing about the defined alias for HTTP access.

You have to define the path to the files in a way that the file system understands. Which probably means to use

```
$download_dir = "H:/Filme/";
```

Comment: Damn, only works partly. 
asdf.txt can be downloaded and displayed correctly (but with whitespaces at the beginning...). 
but when i try to download for example a .jpg, it still doesnt work... 

.doc files got some strange symbols at the beginning if i download them...

Comment: That's because you do not send the correct mime type for the file. `Content-Type: x-type/subtype` will not really work. Downloads should probably use "application/octet-stream".

Comment: Makes no difference :(

Comment: If there are whitespaces in the textfile, then these will mess up any other file as well. Remove them.

Comment: there are no whitespaces in the .txt-file. but when i download it using the script, they appear in front of the text. when i download .doc-files, there are some cryptic symbols at the beginning as well, although they don't appear in the original file.

Comment: Yes, the whitespace is not in that file, but gets added because of your download script. Remove it there.

Comment: Lol, got it. nvm. whitespace in front of <?php :D